Shapiro | gravitational time delay - experimental approach
The calculation for the Shapiro delay is clear, but I am struggling with the measurement.
I see only the measurement of the real two-way radar-echo time-of-flight. But how is the (hypothetical) time-of-flight without the mass or without relativistic corrections determined?
(For the measurement of light deflection the case without the sun is the normal case, with sun means the case of an eclipse.)

You know where the planet (Mars, Venus) is by orbital mechanics. Timing deviations as the radar path to the planet varies from being far from, or near to, the sun is what is observed.

Does one really know the position of the planets within a range of a few kilometers?

You aren't bouncing the radar off the body and measuring the delay to the body. You're bouncing the radar off some other object the other side of the body, and measuring the delay as the radar passes by the body. These alignments don't last long, so you measure how the travel time changes as the two bodies move into alignment then back out of alignment again.

You don't understand the question.

Have you read the journal articles referenced in Wikipedia’s entry?

Not all of them. But I will do that.
